# Submit appears to remain pressed and doesn't submit only on mobile

Tags: javascript, php, dom, button, mobile

Where would be a good place to start looking if the button doesn't submit only on mobile and looks like it remains pressed?

Comment: Does the button have styles applied using the `:hover` CSS pseudo-selector? That can often have side effects on touch devices.

Comment: There is a :focus. I will let you know after I remove it. I will also check if it's onClick or onSubmit and if it has touchstart.

Comment: You could also try to reproduce the issue you have in a sandbox environment, like codesandbox or repl.it